# Windows 8.1 apps won't work after installing CorelDRAW X4

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store-app, coreldraw

Everything was working fine, till I installed CorelDRAW X4. All Windows store apps stopped working. Why has this happened and what can be its solution?

I tried to uninstall CorelDRAW X4 but it didn't help.

Comment: are you sure installing CDX4 caused that? You can test it by restoring windows to an earlier state that CDX4 is not installed. Edit: Try another restore point maybe?

Comment: Yes I am sure because before I installed CDX4 all apps were working fine. after installing it they just open show splash screen and then minimize to taskbar. No App or App store open.
I tried restoring but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found an answer and it worked perfectly for me.

1. Open Registry Editor using regedit.exe.
2. Right click on HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.
3. Click on "Permissions" and in popup click on "Add".
4. In 2nd Popup click on "Advanced".
5. In 3rd Popus click on "Find Now".
6. In "Search Results" click on "All Application Packages" and then click "Ok".
7. Now in 2nd Popup "Select Users or Groups" click again "Ok".
8. In Permissions select under Allow "Read" and Click "Ok".
9. Close the Registry Editor. No need to restart.
10. All Apps Would be working.

It worked for me perfectly.